# Spring @Value always returns a null value

Tags: java, spring

I'm facing an issue with a dev I have to do with Spring (not spring boot).
In a class, I have to retrieve the value of a property defined on a properties files (application.properties).
So, I use the @Value annotation (normally it's easy to use), but it doesn't work in my case.
In my class, I have this code :

```
@Value("${value:'DefaultValue'}")
private String myValue;
```

with the import : `import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;`

My property file contains : `value=a value`

But, when I want to test my application, I always receive a null value (also with the use of the default value).
I try to add deafferents annotations in my class like

```
@Component
```

...

Do you have any suggestion? I'm pretty sure I miss a config somewhere, but I don't know what.

Thanks in advance

Tigrou

Comment: Sure that your class is being scanned(loaded) properly by spring ?

Comment: You are not instantiating the object by yourself, aren't oyu?

Comment: @zXor I'm not sure at all, but as I added the following annotations 
Component
ComponentScan
Configuration
PropertySource("application.properties")
I think it should be enough to let spring scan the class? Or am I wrong?

Comment: If it is `null` you either create an object instance yourself with `new MyObject()` (the `@Component` annotations doesn't matter then because you are still creating a new instance outside the scope of Spring) or you haven't configured a `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer` in your application.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have a PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer  in another class : `@Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        configurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        configurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return configurer;
    }`

Comment: If that is the case, the only conclusion can be you are creating a new instance of that class outside the scope of Spring. And please don't add additional code/information as comments as that is totally unreadable, edit your question instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, no I have the issue in a test class, in a test method => '@Component
public class myClassTest {


@Value("${value:'DefaultValue'}")
private String myValue;
  ... 
  @Test
  public void test() {
System.out.println("test " + test + " " + myValue); }'

=> Only a sysout is performed in my test and I always receive a null value :(

Comment: Let me guess run and controlled by JUnit and not Spring. Which is more or less the same as creating an instance outside the scope of Spring. JUnit doesn't know about Spring so this will simply not work. Also this is crucial information for your question.

Comment: Indeed, it is executed by Junit. So, this can be the issue, that's a good news. Do you have any idea to solve the issue?

Comment: You need to run it with the proper Spring annotations for testing (see the testing chapter) and even then I doubt the `@Value` will be processed (I know `@Autowired` is replaced, but I doubt `@Value`).

Comment: Thanks, now I'am able to retrieve the default value of my property, it's better than nothing, but still not perfect.

Comment: I removed the Junit dependencies and replaced by @ExtendWith annotation. Unfortunattely, the application.properties file is not read correctly

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue ... I had `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean in my config which was non static and resulted in the issue.

Making the bean static solved the issue for me https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/annotation-config/value-annotations.html

> A default lenient embedded value resolver is provided by Spring. It
> will try to resolve the property value and if it cannot be resolved,
> the property name (for example ${catalog.name}) will be injected as
> the value. If you want to maintain strict control over nonexistent
> values, you should declare a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
> bean, as the following example shows:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

> When configuring a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer using
> JavaConfig, the @Bean method must be static.

Answer (score 0):

Every class where you use `@Value` annotation MUST be a spring-managed bean. You can achieve this by adding `@Component` annotation but make sure that you have configured component scan `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "your.package")` in your java configuration, so spring knows where to search for components.

Comment: Regardless, even with `@Component` if you do `new YourClass()` it won't work either. How many annotations you are going to throw at it.

Comment: Spring isn't aware of arbitrary creation through constructors. It violates the Inversion of Control principle, as bean creation, injection and destruction are managed by the ioc-container but not by developer directly.

Comment: Please read my comments... This won't help as he is creating a new instance himself, instead of using the spring provided one.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, with the help of everybody here (special thanks to @M. Deinum I fixed my issue.

So, first thing done, replace the Junit dependeny (use) by a Spring test dependency.
secondly, I've updated my test to be executed with Spring with those lines :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class})
```

This was enough to retrieve the default value of the @Value field.
To retrieve the value I had to add

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
```

in my AppConfig class